# Cannot Checkin in TFS 2013 - Value cannot be null Parameter name: format

Tags: tfs

It has been a week since this has started happening. Whenever I try to check in my code in Visual Studio 2012 I get the following from TFS 2013.

[image: TFS 2013 Error - Value Cannot Be Null]

I've not made any changes to my Visual Studio, and no one else on the team is getting this error.

I'm confused as to the cause of the issue, what can I do to diagnose why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Visual Studio? Are you able to check in a dummyfile or project?

Comment: Is reinstalling VS my only option? :( I tried checking in a simple text file into the WorkSpace, but I get the same error. :(

Comment: Well, to rule out any problems with your current configuration of VS, reinstalling would be a solid option to start with. You could also try a reset: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx

Comment: Does your team use and custom check-in policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the applicable updates for VS2012 to connect to VS2013?

According to *[Compatibility between Team Foundation clients and Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx)*, under *TFS 2013 client support* for VS2012:

> Requires latest Visual Studio 2012 update.  Supports Git with Visual Studio Tools for Git extension.

The latest VS2012 update is Update 4.

Answer (score 67):

I got similar issue. It got resolved by closing the visual studio and opening it again.

Comment: 22 upvotes for the classic 'did you try turning it off and on again' solution. What a time to be alive.

Comment: I had `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: hierarchy` and this fixed it for me too. Just restarted VS2017 and all good.

Comment: When your only contribution to SO brings you 40 upvotes, 3 silver and 3 bronze badges. That must be some sort of unique record on SO I guess. :)

Comment: 50+ now :)  way to go

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using `VS2017`:

I was able to resolve by clearing the contents of the cache folder first:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache
```

Restart and `Run As Admin` and it should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when I tried to annotate a field with RegularExpression data annotation and the error message I tried to get from Resources didn't exist (a merge issue).

```
[RegularExpression(@"^-?\d{1,3}([.,]\d+)?$", 
        ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.Template),
        ErrorMessageResourceName="latitude_incorrect")]
    public Nullable<decimal> Latitude { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your visual studio needs to be opened with a "Run as administrator"

Comment: No, it doesn't solve by running as admin as I have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from here and it is working for my end..
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fe743f8-8d03-462f-823c-f93b2f973af8/visual-studio-2017-team-explorer-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source?forum=tfsversioncontrol